# Concatenate values of elements to a variable with the usage of a template?

Tags: xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

The following data need to be concatenated. But the XML document which I received can have "zero to n" b elements. In other words if there are no b elements the xslt should still work correctly example:

```
 <a>
   <b1>Some</b2>
   <b2>data</b2>
   <b3>what</b3>
   <b4>need</b4>
   <b5>to</b5>
   <b6>be</b6>
   <b7>concatenated</b7>
</a>
```

Expected result

```
<a>
  <b1>Some data what need to be concatenated</b1>
</a>
```

I was trying the following construction but I couldn't made it work.

```
<xsl:variable name="details" select="//b*"/>
<xsl:for-each select="$details">
    <!-- how can I concatenate the values of the b's to a variable????-->
</xsl:for-each>
 <!-- Process the variable for further needs-->
```

I hope some body can give me a hint?
Regards Dirk

Comment: The example data didn't came throught.
    <a>
       <b1>Some</b2>
       <b2>data</b2>
       <b3>what</b3>
       <b4>need</b4>
       <b5>to</b5>
       <b6>be</b6>
       <b7>concatenated</b7>
    </a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use //b* to select all elements starting with b, since XPath is always doing an exact matching without wildcards (perhaps except for namespaces). So you need to use //*[starts-with(name(), "b")] to select the b elements

Then you can do the concatenation is in XPath alone with the string-join function:

```
string-join(//*[starts-with(name(), "b")]/text(), " ")
```

Answer (score 1):

**As simple as this** (complete transformation):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'b')][1]">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
   <xsl:sequence select="../*[starts-with(name(), 'b')]/string()"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()[true()]| *[starts-with(name(), 'b')][position() gt 1]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided (corrected for well-formedness) XML document:**

```
 <a>
   <b1>Some</b1>
   <b2>data</b2>
   <b3>what</b3>
   <b4>need</b4>
   <b5>to</b5>
   <b6>be</b6>
   <b7>concatenated</b7>
 </a>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<a>
   <b1>Some data what need to be concatenated</b1>
</a>
```

Comment: thanks again learned a lot the last 2 days. Yes it works in. But I get Errors during runtime. ERROR]: Ambiguous rule match for /a/text()[1]. How do I need to interprete these?