# xslt variable type element() unable to drill down via xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon, exslt

I am having a this function and transformation build on XSLT 2.0 (please note that the value of the element below is actually filled with correct value, just do not want to copy paste 3 other functions :-) ):

```
<xsl:function name="foo:count_max_nodes_for_each_child_irrelevant_of_level">
    <xsl:param name="root_element"/>
    <xsl:element name="re">
    <xsl:for-each select="$root_element/child::*" >
        <xsl:element name="ch"> <!--{concat('level_1-',position())}-->
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('level_1-',position())" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="max(foo:create_nodes_count_in_levels(foo:count_level_nodes(.,max(./node()[not(node())]/count(ancestor-or-self::node())))))"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:function>


<xsl:variable name="this_root" select="." />
<xsl:variable name="max_vertical_nodes_for_each_child_from_root" as="element()" select="foo:count_max_nodes_for_each_child_irrelevant_of_level($this_root)" />
```

I think this code generates a xml tree stored in variable which can i further drill down..
however when i try this:

```
<xsl:variable name="testin_purposes" select="$max_vertical_nodes_for_each_child_from_root/ch[1]" />
```

no value is returned, I have tried almost everything even the exslt:node-set() but nothing helped... I can this variable "max_vertical_nodes_for_each_child_from_root" sent as parameter, and that parameter has again (at least according to Oxygen) the same structure, but also even in another function/transformation i can not drill down...

Any guesses what am I missing or doing wrong?

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: Consider to post minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem. If a path does not work as expected then it is often a namespace problem but we can't tell without seeing the context.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenate values of elements to a variable with the usage of a template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327033/concatenate-values-of-elements-to-a-variable-with-the-usage-of-a-template)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can contribute something:

A quite simply issue is:

```
<xsl:variable name="testin_purposes" select="$max_vertical_nodes_for_each_child_from_root/ch[1]" />
```

can't select anything, because the structure of your variable is "re/ch".

As a general tip: If a variable doesn't work or contain what you expect: allways check its complete content via

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$variable_name"/>
```

In your case I got

```
<re><ch name="level_1-1"/></re>
```

So (theoretically),

```
<xsl:variable name="testin_purposes" select="$max_vertical_nodes_for_each_child_from_root/rt/ch[1]" />
```

would do the job.

But as Martin Honnen mentioned, there is often a namespace problem. Without having fully understand that issue (to be honest) I personally solved that problem by allways adding a namespace prefix to all elements created by a function or temporal elements not designed for output. I called that namespace prefix "own_t:" and changed your function to

```
    <xsl:function name="foo:count_max_nodes_for_each_child_irrelevant_of_level">
    <xsl:param name="root_element"/>
    <xsl:element name="own_t:re">
        <xsl:for-each select="$root_element/g7ldb:letter_db/child::*">
            <xsl:element name="own_t:ch">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('level_1-',position())"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="'something_here'"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:function>
```

Again without really knowing the background, but as far as I understand it the corect variable type for your purpose is not "element" but "document node". Because (as you've stated yourself) you do not want just one element in there but a hole xml tree.

So, I think

```
 <xsl:variable name="max_vertical_nodes_for_each_child_from_root" as="document-node()">
            <xsl:document>
                <xsl:copy-of select="foo:count_max_nodes_for_each_child_irrelevant_of_level($this_root)"/>
            </xsl:document>
        </xsl:variable>
```

would be the appropriate variable declaration.

And now I was able to use

```
<xsl:value-of select="$max_vertical_nodes_for_each_child_from_root/own_t:re/own_t:ch[1]"/>
```

and get:
"something here".

But be aware: Your function will allways just process ONE element, namely the root element.

If your this_root variable looks like this

```
<root><element1>content</element1><element2>content</element2></root>
```

there is infact just one child of $this_root and that is: "root".